# Wordpress HMTL5 Blank Theme- How to change submenu attributes/justification

Tags: wordpress, html, submenu

We recently migrated our website from Sharepoint to Wordpress with HTML5 Blank theme.

We are trying to figure out how to edit the appearance of sub-menus and their parent menus. Primarily when customizing and editing menus they show up justified right, but published on the page they justify left, and also longer words spill over to the left instead of the right. Please see screenshot below.

Where can we find the edit options to offset submenus and their subsequent menus justify and shift/spill over?

Screenshot of menus being edited

[image: Screenshot of menus being edited]

Screenshot of menus published on homepage

[image: Screenshot of menus published on homepage]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot of your menu's being edited is the way it is displayed in the backend of all WordPress websites. It has not hing to do with the way the menu is rendered in the frontend.

To change the appearance of your menu, you will have to write some custom css. The parent list items will have to be relatively positioned, the child list items will have to be absolutely positioned.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I understand the graphical display of editing menus on the backend does not directly 100% represent the menus on the frontend. 
The screenshot of the back end is to show how we want the menus laid out, and how frustratingly they represent it one way on the backend and the mirror on the frontend. Also I was hoping there would be an option to change this similar to changing our pages in WP-Bakery, because I wouldn't know where to start to write the CSS code to change the menu positons.